# List of methods and properties for cefSharp

Tags: methods, properties, cefsharp

I am looking at cefSharp to replace the webbrowser that comes with VS.
Where is a list of the methods and properties that is has inherent in the binaries?

Answer (score 1):

You currently have two options.

- First option is to look at the `I<SomeThing>` interface definitions. A good starting point is the common interface implemented by the `ChromiumWebBrowser` class across both WinForms and WPF: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp/IWebBrowser.cs and then at the public interface of https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Core/Cef.h
- Second option is that all of it should be included as XML documentation files in the NuGet packages so it provides you with intellisense and documentation in the VS object browser.

I had hoped including the XML doc in the NuGet packages would have triggered http://NuDoq.org to generate pages, but so far no luck with that.